# Should we actively promote the site in the private beta?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

There's a lot of questions floating around about promoting the site, gaining the support of the foundation, etc. - while I agree this is worth discussing now, is it really sensible to try and actively promote it while it's in private beta, and therefore no-one else can access it for a week? I'm aware that's not what's being discussed a lot of the time, but I've seen some people already trying to actively promote it on twitter / facebook / forums.

I'm all for planning how we should go about promoting it now, but if we're too forward with shouting about it when outsiders can't actually use it yet, I think we run the risk of people taking a look, then getting disappointed when they can't access it and subsequently forgetting about it.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed - wait till next week to promote the site.

In the mean time, you can refer users to the Area51 proposal so they can follow the progress.